# Android: strange behavior of activity after searching in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

At the begining an app looks like 'Header 1 Content 1; Header 2 Content 2; Header 3 Content 3'.
When you've pressed "Go to Google Maps" button, this app opened and searched 'North Korea'. When you've returned back, app became 'Header 1 Content 3; Header 2 Content 3; Header 3 Content 3' (all contents are 3)! Why? Happens at least on Android 4.0.4 (official for Huawei Honor).

As you can see, I use ScrollView with LinearLayout in it and add there a view described in **item.xml**.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.HelloWorld"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
package com.example.HelloWorld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addBlock("Header1", "Content1");
        addBlock("Header2", "Content2");
        addBlock("Header3", "Content3");
    }

    public void openMaps(View view) {
        String uri = "geo:0,0?q=North+Korea";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void addBlock(String header, String content) {
        final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        final LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        final TextView headerView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header);
        final TextView contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        if (header.isEmpty()) {
            headerView.setHeight(0);
        }
        headerView.setText(header);
        contentView.setText(content);
        linearLayout.addView(view);
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go to Google Maps"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:onClick="openMaps"/>
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:longClickable="false" android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header"
            android:id="@+id/header" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content"
            android:id="@+id/content" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say with what you have listed in the code. One kind of needs to see the Activity callbacks to see how the state of the Activity is being restored and where it is going to when you say go to Google Maps. I know from experience when you are working with your own ListView inside a ScrollView it is often times a good practice to create a Parcelable data object to hold the state of your object and when the Activity is recreated or (brought back to the front) to restore the state of your view back to what you want it specifically to be. This can be done using the onCreate() and onSavedInstanceState() callbacks if you are using Activities and not Fragments. If you put more information on there I can be of more assistance.

Comment: I have no more influential code in this project. Yes, I use activities.